# Joomla 2.5 ― using administrator components controllers in frontent part of component

Tags: joomla2.5

how can I use the controllers created at

```
/administrator/components/com_mycom/controllers/*
```

in

```
/components/com_mycom/mycom.php
```

In detail:

I have a »log« controller with an »add« method, and I would like to use this from the frontend. I one is not logged in in the backend the task is not executed and a 500 error rises. So just would like to include the backend controllerpath in the frontend, so that `JController::getInstance( 'Mycom' )` still works.

Greetings…

**EDIT:**

After a long time of searching I could find a more or less undocumented Parameter of the:
`JController::getInstance()` method, namely the second one: `$config = array()`. Going through the source code I found out that there is one key of the »config-array« that is of interest, which is: »base_path«.

The call of:

```
JController:getInstance( 'Mycom, array('base_path' =>JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_mycom')' );
```

always delivers the backend controller and one can use them safely in the frontend, **BUT** one must take care that then also the views are taken from the backend side of the component. In my case, I just use it to make ajax-calls so it does not matter, but one needs to be careful with using this method when planning to create »frontend views« with »backend controller«.

Greetings…

Comment: Where did you place this call in the MVC?

Comment: In a controller method....

Comment: do you mean in the components master controller?

Comment: I used it in a method of a/the front end controller. You could also instanciat it in the main component file, but that would effect the template location and other paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had recently a similar problem where I wanted to use the whole CRUD system form back-end also in front-end.

This is the method that worked for me (and I am not saying that this is recommended or best practice):

I've just modeled the folders / file structure from backend. PHP files contained something like:

`require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_mycom/controllers/log.php';`

Comment: thank you, this solution looks good! I found another more or less working solution, see my edit…

Comment: In the respective front-end files which are empty expect the require

Comment: I would also like to use my backend subcontrollers in the frontend, like you the whole CRUD system from backend. The models I get this is not a problem. But the controller functions will be taken from the frontend subcontrollers instead of the backend subcontrollers. Where and how do I have to place your recommendation to use backend subcontroller functions in the frontend?