# Which models to be used ? MVC, Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, directory-structure

I have a Joomla component.

***Backend File Structure***

[image]

***Frontend File Structure***

[image]

In Joomla in the front-end component we can use the back-end models rather than using front-end  models. According to the my knowledge, logic stays in the model. So if we use separate front-end and back-end models and if we come across a logic change we have to change two places instead of one. But if we use back-end models for the front-end too we only have to change the logic in one place. It's easier to maintain.

Which is better method is better ? To create separate models for the fronted  or use the existing back-end models ?

What's the Joomla standard? What's the industry standard? Which method should I use and Why? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: I would use 2 separate models. Keep one specifically for the backend and the other for the frontend to avoid any confusion it might cause. However that's just me, others might think differently ;)

Comment: You should use two models so you can retrieve variables with greater ease etc!

Comment: Even though the core sometimes uses one, it undermines the independence of the two applications plus it just ends up being extremely messy a lot of times, because models in the admin do not have to do things as complex as the front end such as deal with view levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a good question. The problem that you are rising is that of the code duplication that occurs.

If the models are absolutely identical and the code can be reused, have a look at the question  [Joomla 2.5 ― using administrator components controllers in frontend part of component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442052/joomla-2-5-using-administrator-components-controllers-in-frontent-part-of-comp/13450106#13450106).

I think is really a question of code maintenance. I find it always annoying if I fix a bug somewhere that I should always remember that I also need to fix in in the other place also.